# How to implement breadcrumb navigation in Angular 4

Tags: angular, breadcrumbs

I want to implement Breadcrumb navigation with the following menu

**Home > Solutions > Results > Contact**

Currently, I'm using the following routing code

```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

    import { SolutionComponent } from "./solutions.component";
    import { ResultComponent } from "./result/result.component";
    import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';


    const routes: Routes = [
        {
            path: 'home/solutions',
            component: SolutionsComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'home/solutions/result',
            component:ResultComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'home/solutions/result/contact',
            component: ContactComponent
        }
];
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Can anyone suggest sample plunker to implement breadcrumb navigation in ANgular 4

I have created a partial working plunker  https://plnkr.co/edit/iGLJ06zRVYWDYedAtsDW?p=preview

Thanks

Comment: There is a good solution for breadcrumbs in Angular as xng-breadcrumb. https://www.npmjs.com/package/xng-breadcrumb

Answer (score 2):

```
setBreadcrumb() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
        this.displayBreadcrumbList = [];
        if (location.pathname !== '') {
            this.route = location.pathname;
            this.masterBreadcrumbList = this.route.split('/');
            this.masterBreadcrumbList = this.masterBreadcrumbList.slice(1, this.masterBreadcrumbList.length);
            for (let i = 0; i < this.masterBreadcrumbList.length; i++) {
                if (i !== 0) {
                    this.initialUrl = this.displayBreadcrumbList[i - 1];
                } else {
                    this.initialUrl = '/';
                }
                const breadCrumbObj = {
                    name: this.masterBreadcrumbList[i],
                    url: this.initialUrl + this.masterBreadcrumbList[i],
                    id: i
                };
                this.displayBreadcrumbList.push(breadCrumbObj);
            }
        } else {
            this.route = 'Home';
        }
    });
}
<ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a class="breadcrumb-text" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li *ngFor="let breadLink of displayBreadcrumbList" class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" [routerLink]="breadLink.url" class="breadcrumb-text">{{breadLink.name }}</a></li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: Just THat camel case missing

Comment: you are  right bust you should be add decleration of vars :--
 export class BreadcrumbComponent implements OnInit {
  displayBreadcrumbList:Array<any>;
  route:string='';
  initialUrl:string='';
  masterBreadcrumbList:Array<any> ; 
  constructor(private router:Router ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setBreadcrumb();
  }

Answer (score 1):

> Do this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
        {
            path: 'home/solutions',
            component: SolutionsComponent,
            data: { breadcrumb: 'sample breadcrumb' },
        },
        {
            path: 'home/solutions/result',
            component:ResultComponent,
            data: { breadcrumb: 'sample breadcrumb' },
        },
        {
            path: 'home/solutions/result/contact',
            component: ContactComponent,
            data: { breadcrumb: 'sample breadcrumb' },
        }
];
```

Comment: Thanks, but it will be very useful if you could create a plunker for this, I have tried with ng2-breadcrumbs but it is not working

Comment: I have created a partial working plunker, here is the link for plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/iGLJ06zRVYWDYedAtsDW?p=preview),   Thank you

Comment: How breadcrumbs are implemented with ng5-breadcrumb, Im trying to use ng5-breadcrumb

Answer (score 0):

Any breadcrumb solution has to handle -

1. declarative approach of defining breadcrumbs in routing
2. Dynamic asynchronous way to update any route by a different label
3. way to skip specific routes from displaying in breadcrumbs

I have created an Angular library to handle all these, called **xng-breadcrumbs** - https://github.com/udayvunnam/xng-breadcrumb

feel free to check, An Angular app developed showing the breadcrumbs usage - https://xng-breadcrumb.netlify.com

Angular library planning, creation, and continuous release is well [documented in this medium article](https://medium.com/@udayvunnam/https-medium-com-udayvunnam-be-the-thanos-of-your-angular-library-320f93ddc9ec)

Comment: I'm using xng-breadcrumb and the breadcrumbs are being created but without the links. The HTML code includes the <a> but the breadcrumbs are not clickable. Any idea?